# FactoryGirl rename auto generated files

Tags: factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-5

When using FactoryGirl and generating a new model `company` it generates a factory as well in: `spec/factories/companies.rb`.

For personal preference and the way I use `ctrl+p` in sublime text I want to rename the auto generated files to `spec/factories/companies_factory.rb`.

I've viewed the generators documentation but I don't see any way to overide another gems implementation.

A point in the right direction will be `super` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to your `application.rb` should do what you want:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.factory_girl suffix: 'factory'
end
```

Comment: If you have a chance can you point me to some docs showing how this works.

Comment: The configuration section of the README at https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails points out how to use a custom suffix for your factories. If you are interested in how the code actually works, `bundle open factory_girl_rails` will open the gem code into an editor - you want the `lib/generators/factory_girl/model/model_generator.rb` file.

Comment: Awesome thank you. I didn't know about the bundle open command.